# calculate the total capacity of a reference

Tags: laravel

I have a conference that has two registration types "general" and plus.

The general registration type has a capacity of "100".

The plus registration type has a capacity of "50".

So the total capacity of the conference is "150".

But Im getting "1080" with the code below instead of "150". Do you know where is the issue?

```
public function stats($id)
    $conference = Conference::where('id',$id)->firstOr(function(){
        return redirect('/');
    });
    $conferenceID = $conference->id;
    $capacityOfRegistrationTypes = RegistrationType::with('conferences')->sum('capacity');
    dd($capacityOfRegistrationTypes);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're summing the capacity of all registration types regardless of conference. That is probably not what you want. I have no idea how your tables look like or what they hold so I am assuming that you have multiple conferences and each one has multiple entries in the registration type.

You should go the other way around:

```
$conferences = Conference::with('registrationTypes')->get();
```

Now to get the capacity of each conference you can do:

```
$conferences->mapWithKeys(function ($conference) {
     return [ $conference->id => $conference->registrationTypes->sum('capacity') ];
});
```

To do this for a specific conference you can write:

```
$capacity = Conference::with('registrationTypes')->find($id)->registrationTypes->sum('capacity');
```

This will five you an array that has the conference id as the key and the capacity as the value.

If you want to work it the way you are currently you can limit your query:

```
$capacityOfRegistrationTypes = RegistrationType::with('conferences')
     ->whereHas('conferences', function ($query) use ($id) {
          $query->id = $id;
      })
     ->sum('capacity');
```

Comment: Thanks, but like that appears "Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::conferences()
". Using "$capacityOfRegistrationTypes = RegistrationType::with('conferences')
     ->whereHas('conferences', function ($query) use ($id) {
          $query->id = $id;
      })
     ->sum('capacity');".

Comment: With "$conferences->mapWithKeys(function ($conference) {
     return [ $conference->id => $conference->registrationType->sum('capacity') ];
});
" shows "Call to undefined relationship [registrationType] on model [App\Conference]."

Comment: Conference model "
class Conference extends Model
{


    public function registrationTypes(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\RegistrationType', 'conference_id');
    }


}
".

Comment: Was missing an `s` then try the update and let me know as for the first one I don't know what the issue is there.

Comment: Just double check your relationship definitions to make sure they match. Might be worth updating your question with some more code from your models

Comment: Thanks, like that it shows "Collection {#347 ▼
  #items: array:4 [▼
    1 => 150
    5 => 100
    9 => 100
    12 => 20
  ]
}". But the conference with id 1 has only two registration types one with capacity "100" and other with capacity "50", so it should show "150".

Comment: That collection does seem to indicate that you have 4 conferences in your database and conference with id 1 seems to have capacity 150

Comment: Thanks, but what is necessary is to get the total capacity of a specific conference, in this case of the conference with id "1".